# How to use Poisson distribution to generate bursts of data packets

Tags: probability-distributions, computer-science, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I’m doing some research on computer networking and trying to use a model for simulating burst of sending data packets. After searching around for a while it seems that the most common one for this purpose is to use *Poisson distribution*. But I’m having a hard time wrapping my head around it.

If I understand the distribution correctly it should be possible to use Poisson distribution to generate X number of bursts, when to execute each burst in a given time period Z, where each burst contains a random number of data packets.

Am I correct in this assumption? If yes, then how would such an algorithm look?

Comment: The Poisson distribution is a consequence of the underlying process that generates the events "with a known constant mean rate and independently of the time since the last event." How exactly are you modeling the computer network?

Answer (score 1):

Generally just poisson is not enough, since that describes the number of bursts but not the timing. So you may use Poisson to determine how many bursts in some interval $[0,T]$ but not the timing of the bursts. Even if you assume regular transmission times, $kT,k\geq 1,$ you still need to decide exactly at which of those times there is a transmission.

If you have a stationary setup, you can generate an i.i.d. sequence $X_i$ with each $X_i$ exponentially distributed with some mean.

This gives you burst times,
$$T_1=X_1,T_2=X_1+X_2,\ldots.$$

Then you could use the poisson distribution to determine the *number* of packets in each burst.